# MINGW compile error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, dereference, mingw32

While building the below code in eclipse I am getting void value not ignored as it ought to be, generally this error is encounter when we are expecting a value from a function returning void. But here I am not using any function, I am using a void pointer.
Code is below:

```
typedef struct MessageName_T 
{
MPM_ParameterName_t  parameterName;
uint32_t minRange;
uint32_t maxRange;
bool_t isInRange;
DataType_t dataType;
bool_t isValueNa;
void* const data;
}MessageName_t ;


MessageName_t messagefr[3] =
/* Parameter,                 Minimum,       Maximum,      isInRange    dataType     isValueNa    data*/
{
  { Parameter,                Minimum,       Maximum,      isInRange,    dataType,     isValueNa,  &stuctureA.data1},
  { Parameter1,               Minimum1,      Maximum1,     isInRange1,   dataType1,   isValueNa1,  &stuctureA.data2},
  { Parameter2,               Minimum2,      Maximum2,     isInRange2,   dataType2,   isValueNa2,  &stuctureA.data3}
}

void rangecheck(int index)
{
   if(messagefr[index].isValueNa == FALSE)
   {
     if(*(messagefr[index].data) >= (messagefr[index].minRange) &&
    *(messagefr[index].data) <= (messagefr[index].maxRange))
 {printf("N");
     messagefr[index].messagefr=TRUE;
 }
 else
 {printf("Y");
     messagefr[index].isInRange =FALSE;
 }
}
else
{
  NOP();
}
}
```

In line `*(messagefr[index].data) >= (messagefr[index].minRange)` the error "void value not ignored as it ought to be" is coming.
data is void pointer and I am assigning it the value of `&stuctureA.data1`.
Now while accessing this information of data i.e `*(messagefr[index].data)` I am getting the error, if I use `(messagefr[index].data)` I am getting address assigned to data.

Comment: 1) the call to `NOP()` is a complete do nothing.  suggest removed the enclosing `else` code block.  2) the field `isInRange` is defined as containing `false` or `true`, however, the code is comparing against `FALSE`  3) several of the field types in the `MessageName_t` struct are not defined.   For use to debug this for you, the posted code needs to cover all the details, not be some snippet from a larger block of code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}',  Suggest each indent be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `messagefr[index].messagefr=TRUE;`,  There is not field named: `messagefr`.   Suggest 1) point out which line is giving you the problem, post the actual complete error message, post the definitions for all the 'homegrown' data types.

Comment: this line in the struct definition: `void* const data;` should probably be `int * data`

Comment: 1)Else part is kept due to coding standards that I have to follow,2) It is compared against false bcoz if value I receive is NA I.e 2^n for where n is data type, then no need to check for whether it is in range 3) the code is way to long to be kept here that's why the snippet.  I am using void* const data as information I get is not always gonna be int, it can be uint8, uint16, int32, float64 etc. Hence the void poonter

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the data type of `messagefr[index].data` is `void *`, and you cannot dereference it.

You need to cast it to some other complete type before you can derefence it.

Considering you are comparing the value with `minRange`, something like

```
 *(uint32_t *)(messagefr[index].data)
```

will work.

---

To add some elaboration regarding the *why* part, first let's see about complete and incomplete types. Quoting

> ...] an object type may be
>   **incomplete** (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or
>   **complete** (having sufficient information).

Now, coming to chapter §6.5.3.2, unary `*` operator,

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. If the operand has type *‘‘pointer to type’’*, the result has type *‘‘type’’*. [...]

However, from chapter §6.2.5/19, we know

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
>   cannot be completed.

Thus, a pointer to `void` cannot be dereferenced because, the resulting type (`void`) is incomplete and the size required for the resulting object cannot be determined. so, we need to cast the pointer to a complete type before attempt to dereference.

Comment: then how can i extract the information from data or a void *

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Any better now? :)

Comment: Thanks , type casting heped . I haven't done much coding yet just starting a few things , appreciate the effort mate :)